# Probability- 6 digit number that is built from the numbers 2,5,6,9

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random, expected-value, variance

A random 6 digit number is picked that is built only from the numbers $2, 5, 6, 9.$

1. What is the probability that the number can be divided by $3$?
2. What is the probability that the number can be divided by $6$?
3. What is the expected value of the number?
4. What is the variance of the number?

I am stuck the 3rd question... I know how to solve the $4$th part with the next equation- [variance and expected value connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKi96.png) but have no idea how to even find the expected value..

And about the variance-
I have $2$ possible answers I got but I do not know what is correct-

a.  $6.313\times10^{10)}$, my way of getting this answer is- $E(x^2)=36.5\dots,E^2(x)=30.25\dots,$ so then $E(x^2)-E^2(x)=6.313\times 10^{10}=V(x).$

b. $3.13\times10^{11}$

Which variance is correct?

Answer (score 2):

The expect value of the thousand digit is $\frac{2+5+6+9}{4}=\frac{22}{4}$

Similar for all other digits.

So the expect value is $100000\cdot\frac{22}{4}+10000\cdot\frac{22}{4}+1000\cdot\frac{22}{4}+100\cdot\frac{22}{4}+10\cdot\frac{22}{4}+\cdot\frac{22}{4}=611110.5$

Comment: Thank you!! So is the variance 6.313*(10^10)?

Comment: Wait, sorry, but we have the 100,000 as well- so the expect value should be- 611110.5? Am I right?

Comment: @Kwigy yeah it should be 6 digits. See my edit.

Comment: thank you, is my variance right? Or is it 3.3*10^11?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Since we don't have $0$ in our number list, all these numbers have the same probability of being in ones, tens, hundreds or thousands. Also by symmetry, each number has the same number of occurrences in total. So actually you can consider just the numbers $222222,555555,666666,999999$ to find the expectation.

Comment: Thank you! So is the expect value 611110.5?

Comment: Oh, it was a 6 digit number, I thought it was 4 digit. But it is similar and yes it gives 611110.5. But this is more intuitive way, I think abc...'s answer is more formal.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Do you have any clue about the variance? Which one of my answers is correct?

Comment: I found variance as $7.716033950625 \times 10^{10}$ from $Var(X) = E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.

Comment: Thank you, how did you do it? Its not close at all compared to what I got... I did use this equation, but got very different numbers than you.... I mean: E(x^2)=36.5.....E^2(x)=30.25... So then E(x^2)-E^2(x)=6.313*(10^10)=V(x)... Is it correct?

Comment: $E[X^2]$ is the expectation of the square of numbers constructed in a way we are given. Therefore, I just found $E[X^2] = \frac{222222^2+555555^2+666666^2+999999^2}{4}$. How did you find $E[X^2]$ can you explain it as well?

Comment: Well I did it different- my way is: E(x^2)= (2^2)/4+ (5^2)/4+ (6^2)/4+ (9^2)/4=36.5.. I did not understand why did you multiply all of the number by 100,000... Why did you do that?

Comment: Because here, our random variable $X$ is a 6-digit number constructed from the numbers $2,5,6,9$. Then what is $X^2$?

Comment: X^2 needs to be 36.5, right? I mean I used only the possibility of the digits-numbers... Why isnt it right?

Comment: No, $X^2$ is the square of a 6-digit number. So $E[X^2]$ is the expectation of square of randomly generated 6-digit number constructed by using $2,5,6,9$.

Answer (score 0):

The number is the weighted sum of the six digits with weights $1,10 ,100 \cdots$.

If $N= a X + b Y$ and $X,Y$ are random independent variables with the same distribution (i.i.d), then if each of them has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ then you know that the mean and variance of $N$ are given by  ...

refer [to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) and  [to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) Wikipedia articles.

Comment: Thanks, but what should the N represent?

Comment: @Kwigy: once you extend the concept of linear combination of i.i.d. random variables $N=X_1+10X_2 +100X_3 +\cdots$ will represent your number, and $X_k$ a random variable uniformly distributed over $\{2,5,6,9\}$, thus having mean .. and variance .., so that $N$ will have mean .. and variance ...

Comment: Thanks you very much!! About the variance- which one of my answers is right?

Comment: none, it is $6.25 \cdot (1+10+100+ \cdots)=6.25 \cdot 1111\cdots)$

Comment: So its the 6.313*10^10? Thats exactly what I did and the answer I got..

Comment: where did you get 6.313 and 10^10 ?? does not N have six digits ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I did it in a slightly different way- like that: 6.25*(1^2+10^2+100^2+1000^2+10000^2+100000^2)=6.13*10^10.... Why isnt it right?

Comment: Sorry indeed, my fault, yes your calculation is then right !